# --scan --pattern *some_numbers* couldn't find most of my keys

Tags: redis

My redis store keys that looked like this

```
behavior:5c3c841c6efcbd1a6c066b48#20210125
behavior:5ea04f8b3d79784a29e02d37#20210110#submissionCount
kelas:5c73be3be611a06042041f0a#behavior:5f9a70b8c7f67353e8cd5969#20210104#studentCount
student:5c497fdd422c7d511918cc78#behavior:5c49114902b1de4a801b556b#20210123
teacher:5ef1c48fa4fee10f9817b5b2#20210126
```

But now I want to delete some of the keys. So I thought running this

```
redis-cli -n 1 --scan --pattern *202101* | xargs redis-cli unlink
```

will delete all the keys listed above, since all the keys above have `202101` inside it. But I was wrong. Is there any way I can delete my keys by supplying pattern such as above?

Comment: **What** is wrong? Your script works for me.

Comment: That's the thing. I ssh into my ubuntu redis server and run the script above, but when I use Another Redis DeskTop Manager and search for `202101`, still tons of results came out. among the results are `kelas:5c73be3be611a06042041f0a#behavior:5f9a6f7ebecd1f547647a326#20210123#studentCount` , `student:5c3d66986efcbd1a6c066c38#behavior:5eec7ed6fb09fd54ba64aec6#20210112` where you can see there's `202101` in there